# Простое регулярное выражение

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Есть выражение `/[0-9]{5}/` должно проверять поле на наличие пяти цифр от `0` до `9`. Но если ввести шесть цифр, то проверка проходит. Подскажите, что не так?

```
var zipReg = /[0-9]{5}/;
 if(!zip.match(zipReg)){
 ...
 }
```

Comment: Потому что 5 цифр внутри 6 цифр, ясное дело, содержатся.  
ТС, похоже, не на наличие цифр надо проверять, а ограничить пятью цифрами.

Comment: понял, спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/[0-9]{5}/ ( оно же /\d{5}/) ищет в строке подстроку содержащую 5 цифр подряд. Тоесть в вашем коде пройдет и такая строка :

```
 "у меня тут 5 цифр 12345".match(/[0-9]{5}/) // true
```

Если нужна провекра на наличие конкретно строки из 5 цифр следует добавить символ начала строки ^ и конца оной $:

```
"у меня тут 5 цифр 12345".match(/^[0-9]{5}$/) // false
"12345".match(/^[0-9]{5}$/) // true
"123456".match(/^[0-9]{5}$/) // false
```

Ну конечно для проверки лучше использовать test , а не match, потому что матч возвращает подстроку если найдет сходство.

Answer (score 1):

например так `/^\d{5}$/`

Comment: Спасибо, а чего [0-9] не проходит? Вроде такую же функцию выполняет?

Comment: VenZell в своём комментарии ответил вам на этот вопрос.

Comment: и, кстати,
вместо zip.match(zipReg) в вашем случае правильнее использовать  /^\d+$/.test(zip)